# Pig jobs not running on hadoop 2.6

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

When I execute the below dump command, it stop in the 0% complete and not continuing for next step. How to track the issue .

```
grunt> a = load '/user/hduser1/file1' using PigStorage(',') as (usernames:chararray, password:chararray, price:int);
2015-12-25 10:34:26,471 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
grunt> dump a;                                                                                                      
2015-12-25 10:34:33,862 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2015-12-25 10:34:33,904 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-12-25 10:34:33,910 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2015-12-25 10:34:33,951 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2015-12-25 10:34:34,069 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2015-12-25 10:34:34,088 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-12-25 10:34:34,088 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-12-25 10:34:34,158 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-12-25 10:34:34,197 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2015-12-25 10:34:34,425 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2015-12-25 10:34:34,432 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2015-12-25 10:34:34,432 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2015-12-25 10:34:34,432 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2015-12-25 10:34:34,435 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2015-12-25 10:34:35,464 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1328911758/tmp304593952/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-12-25 10:34:35,519 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1328911758/tmp1133010181/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-12-25 10:34:35,575 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1328911758/tmp-1601875197/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-12-25 10:34:35,641 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1328911758/tmp1137978977/guava-11.0.2.jar
2015-12-25 10:34:36,218 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1328911758/tmp325144073/joda-time-2.1.jar
2015-12-25 10:34:36,259 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2015-12-25 10:34:36,267 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2015-12-25 10:34:36,267 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2015-12-25 10:34:36,267 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2015-12-25 10:34:36,304 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2015-12-25 10:34:36,305 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2015-12-25 10:34:36,311 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2015-12-25 10:34:36,344 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-12-25 10:34:36,706 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2015-12-25 10:34:36,782 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-12-25 10:34:36,782 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-12-25 10:34:36,820 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2015-12-25 10:34:36,972 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:1
2015-12-25 10:34:37,483 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_1451017152672_0001
2015-12-25 10:34:37,664 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner - Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
2015-12-25 10:34:38,078 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted application application_1451017152672_0001
2015-12-25 10:34:38,221 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p:8088/proxy/application_1451017152672_0001/
2015-12-25 10:34:38,221 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1451017152672_0001
2015-12-25 10:34:38,222 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases a
2015-12-25 10:34:38,222 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: a[1,4],a[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2015-12-25 10:34:38,243 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2015-12-25 10:34:38,243 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1451017152672_0001]
```

Find the Image for the application.

[image: Application 1]

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMwOq.png)

Comment: It could be the issue with the configuration of the laptop. It is not progressing at all. Also what is the size of the file?

Comment: It is 1KB file. In hive for simple select query, it giving output. For select and group by it freezes. In Pig local mode it is giving output, whereas in mapreduce mode it freezes.

Comment: Can you check memory/disk consumption while you run this job?

Comment: How to check memory/disk consumption while running the job?